# PrestaShop - retrieving products via API

Tags: codeigniter-2, prestashop-1.5

Is there a way to build up an array of PrestaShop products through the API so that I can use them in external application?

I simply want something like this:

```
array(
    0 => array(
        'name' => 'Some product',
        'image' => 'path/to/image.jpg',
        'id' => 1,
        'description' => 'Some description of the product here',
        'path' => 'path/to/product'
    ),
    ...
    999 => array(
        ...
    )
);
```

I know of the webservice call where `array('resource' => 'products', 'display' => 'full')` but I really do not know how to get to the array I need from the content returned from this webservice call. All I want to do is to display a product scroller on an external website, where each image links to the product in the shop.

I am using Prestashop 1.5.6.2 and CodeIgniter 2.1.4. The product scroller must be shown in the CI app.

**Edit 1**
The closest I have come sofar is this: `$product = new Product(1, false, 1);` for product number 1, but it does not contain the image.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
require_once('PSWebServiceLibrary.php');

$url = 'http://example.com';
$webService = new PrestaShopWebservice($url, 'EXAMPLEAPIKEY', false);

$opt['resource'] = 'products';
$opt['display'] = 'full';
$xml = $webService->get($opt);
$productNodes = $xml->products->children();
$products = array();
foreach ($productNodes as $product) {
  $nameLanguage = $product->xpath('name/language[@id=1]');
  $name = (string) $nameLanguage[0];
  $idImage = (string) $product->id_default_image;
  $image = '/img/p/';
  for ($i = 0; $i < strlen($idImage); $i++) {
    $image .= $idImage[$i] . '/';
  }
  $image .= $idImage . '.jpg';
  $id = (int) $product->id;
  $descriptionLanguage = $product->xpath('description/language[@id=1]');
  $description = (string) $descriptionLanguage[0];
  $path = '/index.php?controller=product&id_product=' . $product->id;
  $products[] = array('name' => $name, 'image' => $image, 'id' => $id, 'description' => $description, 'path' => $path);
}
```

Comment: Thanks as always, yenshirak! I will test this a.s.a.p. You are a life saver!